# Understanding the multiple changes in `/dev` after inserting usb

Tags: filesystems, mount, udev, devices

Want some clarification about changes under `/dev` when I plug in a usb flash drive.

---

`ls /dev` also doesn't output anything about `sdb`

`ls /dev/bus/usb/004` just outputs `001`

`lsusb` doesn't mention anything about `Bus 004 Device 003`.

I run `journalctl -f`, and plug in a usb drive and in the output is:

in the output is

```
Jul 20 18:06:40 jordan kernel: scsi host6: usb-storage 4-2:1.0
Jul 20 18:06:40 jordan mtp-probe[2196098]: checking bus 4, device 3: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4/4-2"
Jul 20 18:06:40 jordan mtp-probe[2196098]: bus: 4, device: 3 was not an MTP device
Jul 20 18:06:40 jordan mtp-probe[2196099]: checking bus 4, device 3: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4/4-2"
Jul 20 18:06:40 jordan mtp-probe[2196099]: bus: 4, device: 3 was not an MTP device
```

not sure what a lot of this means, but the emphasis is `bus: 4, device: 3`

followed soon after by

```
Jul 20 18:06:44 jordan kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 1953458176 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/931 GiB)
Jul 20 18:06:44 jordan kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
Jul 20 18:06:44 jordan kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 47 00 10 08
Jul 20 18:06:44 jordan kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
Jul 20 18:06:44 jordan kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
```

with emphasis on `[sdb]`

now `ls /dev` output includes `sdb` and `sdb1` (with my understanding that `sdb1` is the partition on sdb).  It is also my understanding (though I may be wrong) that `sdb` is controlled by `sda` and that the control continues with every other letter of the alphabet.

and `ls /dev/bus/usb/004` outputs both `001` and `003`

there are corresponding changes in the output of `lsusb` and `lsblk`

so my question is: what is the difference between the new `003` file under `/dev/bus/usb` and the `sdb`/`sdb1` files?

I understand that the `sdb`/`sdb1` files are what you use to mount, partition, and make file systems with `mnt`/`fdisk`/`mkfs`. But I still don't have a deep understanding of what these files are.

I also don't have an understanding of what the new `003` file is:perhaps just an indicator that something is physically plugged in? What can you do with this file?

What would be a good resource or book to go through to get a good understanding of what is going on?

Ran into this while going through Chapter 15 (Storage Media) of *The Linux Command Line* by William Shotts.

by the way, I'm running Arch Linux even though I should probably be running an easier distro as a novice

Comment: For additional fun try `udevadm monitor` -- `man udevadm`